# if condition getting executed even though the condition is not satisfied

Tags: shell, if-statement

Whats wrong in my script?

im trying to start the oracle listener & a service which uses a java process.

But if condition getting executed even though the condition is not satisfied...(i.e)
when value of this is (ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l) is 1 (listener is running) , if condition alone executing.
below is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

mydate=date --rfc-3339=seconds
logFile=/home/user/Pictures/ostart.log
service=oatxpress
service1=listener

if [[ $(ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l) -eq 0 ]] && [[ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep java | wc -l) -eq 0 ]];
echo "$(ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l)" >>$logFile
echo "$mydate :  $service1 and $service is not running!!!" >>$logFile
then
lsnrctl start
service oatxpress start
echo "$mydate :  $service1 and $service is started via script!!!" >>$logFile

elif [ $(ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l) -eq 0 ];
echo "$mydate :  $service1 is not running!!!" >>$logFile
then
lsnrctl start
echo "$mydate :  $service1 is started via script!!!" >>$logFile

elif  [ $(ps -ef | grep -v root | grep java | wc -l) -eq 0 ];
echo "$mydate :  $service is not running!!!" >>$logFile
then
service oatxpress start
echo "$mydate :  $service is started via script!!!" >>$logFile

else
echo "$mydate :  $service & $service1 are running!!!" >>$logFile
fi
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. Instead of formating all lines individually with ` select it all and press the `{ }` button in the editor instead

Comment: okay, but the code is readable right

Comment: Now it is, it was not before

Comment: Can you use `listercount=$(ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l) ` and `javacount=..`? The next control statements will be easier to write.

Comment: i could nt assign (ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l)  to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Your format is not what you intend.

You are writing `if cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; then...`, when you intend to write `if cmd1; then cmd2; cmd3`  In other words, you are using `[[..]] && [[...]]` to check some process counts but ignore those values, then you do two echo statements; if the 2nd echo succeeds then the script enters the first clause and invokes `lsnctrl start; services ...`.  Just move your `then` to be before the echos.  That is:

```
if [[ ...
then ...
    echo ... 
    echo ...
elif ...
then 
    echo ...
else
    echo ...
fi
```

Comment: i did as u told..like this:
if [[ ...
then ...
    echo ... 
    echo ...
elif ...
then 
    echo ...
else
    echo ...
fi

but  now:
when listerner & java is '0' , its going to else condition to last.
its is not checking for '&& ' condition ..
can you please help on that?

{if [[ $(ps -ef | grep -v root | grep LISTENER | wc -l) -eq 0 ]] && [[ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep java | wc -l) -eq 0 ]];
then
lsnrctl start
service oatxpress start
echo "$mydate :  $service1 and $service is started via script!!!" >>$logFile

Comment: There are other issues with this script.  For example, `ps | grep LISTENER` is likely to output a line for the grep process.  This is not the right approach.